# XSLT How to create xml tags from from rich text data

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

I am using xsl to transform xml to xml. Could you please help me to write xsl code to convert input to output?

Given input:

```
    <ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
    <THE-VALUE>
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498885">Main Description</h1>
            <p>The main description text goes here.</p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498886">Key Consideration</h1>
            <p>The key consideration text goes here.</p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498887">Skills</h1>
            <p>The Skills text goes here.</p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498888">Synonyms</h1>
            <p>The Synonyms text goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </THE-VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
```

Expected output:

```
<MainDescription><![CDATA[The main description text goes here.]]></MainDescription>
<KeyConsiderations><![CDATA[The key consideration text goes here.]]></KeyConsiderations>
<Skills>The skills text goes here.</Skills>
<Synonyms>The synonyms text goes here.</Synonyms>
```

Comment: I am very new to xslt. Could any one please provide the solution with xslt-1.0?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (with prefix 'x' bound to the xhtml namespace)

```
<xsl:template match="THE-VALUE/x:div">
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="x:h1">
  <xsl:element name="{translate(current-group()[1], ' ', '')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[2]"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Actually this doesn't really need grouping: you could equally well do `<xsl:for-each select="h1">` and then refer to the two elements in the group as `.` and `following-sibling::p[1]` respectively. That is:

```
  <xsl:template match="THE-VALUE/x:div">
    <xsl:for-each select="x:h1">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(., ' ', '')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-eac>
  </xsl:template>
```

The latter solution will work in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: How to put values as rich text under CDATA?

Comment: When I use xsl:template current-group()[2] gives error invalid xpath. How to solve it? Also, what should be added to template to insert values in CDATA ?

Comment: If current-group()[2] gives an error then you're probably using an XSLT 1.0 processor. I gave you a 2.0 answer because you tagged the question xslt 2.0.

Comment: The CDATA tags in your desired output are completely pointless and reflect a poor understanding of XML. However if you really believe you need them, use `xsl:output/@cdata-section-elements`.

Comment: I am very new to xslt. Could you please provide the solution in xslt-1.0?

Comment: Done. (------------------)